# Android 6 Marshmallow Settings.Global.getInt for wifi always returns wrong value?

Tags: java, android

Reading the **WIFI_ON** System setting on an **Android 6.0(API 23) Marshmallow** device seems to always returns **0**. This code works well on **19 ( Kit kat )** and older builds. Are there reasons why it is not working on Android Marshmallow?

```
//api level < 17
int wifiState = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.WIFI_ON, -1);

//api levep 17+

int wifiState = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.WIFI_ON, -1);


int mobileDataState = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", -1);
```

*For mobile data state, it was never documented so this doesn't come as a surprise. Are there any documented changes with regards to the access of system settings?*

Comment: getInt (ContentResolver cr, String name,  int def) Is this the right format?

Comment: Yes that is. I missed that @FebiMathew